# How to import Surface for AIDL?

Tags: java, android, gradle, aidl

I need to use Surface in my AIDL module, but I'm unable to import android.view.Surface in my .aidl file.

Surface is a parcelable class, how can I import it in my AIDL file? I'm using Gradle. Other similar questions either use Android.mk or try to use classes that aren't parcelable.